# OS X Yosemite attempts to eject external drives after sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, external-disk

I have 2 external drives that I use respectively for Time Machine and for all my work. I installed OS X Yosemite today and now every time my iMac goes to sleep (I never turn my macs off) it attempts to eject them. This never happened before and is a pain as all my work could potentially get lost or corrupted. Help!

Comment: Don't have an answer but seeing the same problem and it resulted in a Western Digital USB drive being corrupted to the point it's not usable.

Comment: I have found this thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6607988?start=0&tstart=0 so I'm going to try it and see if it solves this particular problem...

Comment: @Valerie, i have the same problem. A LaCie, 2BIg with Thunderbolt. What are you using (usb/thunderbolt) and which brand?

Comment: @Rogier, I use a 250Gb Freecom external drive for Time Machine, and a 1Tb LaCie ext. drive that I partitioned in 2 for all my work.

I still haven't found a solution so I back up stuff on Dropbox and I also stick new projects that I work on on my HD so that they don't get ejected! (all my apps are on the HD).

I am a bit messy with files and stuff (I am not a tekkie person!) but I don't think this problem is something that I created, as it seems that Yosemite has many bugs.

Comment: @Valerie, well i had the same problem with Mavericks (so its not only Yosemite). But, i use thunderbolt. Do you use USB or Thunderbolt? I filed a bug report with Apple, but they make jump some though some hoops, not really handy. I also tried disabling spotlight for the external disks, but not dice.

Comment: @Rogier, I use USB. Yes I disabled spotlight too but it made no difference... I should have stayed with Mountain Lion!! Tell me if you ever find a fix...

Comment: Hi @Valerie, i did some further testing. For me with USB3 it seems to work, but thunderbolt 2 it doesn't. Technically, i guess, these are different problems.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem, but since installed an app called "Mountain". It allows me to customize which volumes to eject and also re-connect for me on wake. It is not a free app, but it's worth the $5.99 (as of the time I write this).

http://appgineers.de/mountain/

Note, I don't work for them nor am I connected to them in any way. I just like the app and have had great results with it doing exactly what you're doing and more. (I move my macbookpro from 3 locations, where I have different external volume configurations.)